# Is it just the way it is we do not say: consider to do something?

Tags: grammar, idioms, idiomatic-language

We can say:

1. We will continue to support Windows 10.
2. We will continue supporting Windows 10.

However, we say

> I will consider going fishing.

but cannot say

> I will consider to go fishing.

Is it just the way it is?  Just like: nobody says it this way and so we won't say it this way?  It is like in Hong Kong, if the waiter gives you a glass of water, and you say "thank you" in Cantonese, it is considered to be weird, because the common practice is to say, "You shouldn't" (meaning I am not entitled to your service, to mean thank you for giving me the water in a humble way).

Comment: The short answer is that some verbs are like that.  I like to ski, I like skiing, I want to ski, but not *I want skiing*.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a catenative sentence.  There is a clause headed by the verb "consider" and instead of an object, the clause is completed by another clause "going fishing", headed by the participle verb "going".

It is called "catenative" (from a Latin word meaning chain) because there is a "chain" of verbs.

The second verb in the chain is usually either an infinitive (to do) or a participle-gerund (doing).  The first verb determines what form the second verb should take.

Look at the [wiktionary page on catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs#:%7E:text=Have%20you%20considered%20working%20at%20the%20factory%3F) It shows that "consider" is followed by a participle-gerund.  On the other hand "continue" [may be followed by either](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs#:%7E:text=It%20continued%20to%20rain.) an infinitive or a participle with no difference in meaning.

That page is quite long, but native English speakers follow all the rules on that page without thinking, so it is quite important for learners to know which verbs are followed by an infinitive and which are followed by a participle.  This is a grammar rule of English, so it is more important than choice to say "thank you" or "you shouldn't" in Cantonese.

Comment: I don't think it is "native speakers follow all these rules"... I think it is more like from the way people speak, the rules are written

Comment: That is true, but a bit empty.  Consider Cantonese, it has grammar.  you can't just put words together in any order. English is just the same. There is grammar, and part of the grammar of English is that "consider to go fishing" is not an "allowed" sequence of words.  So, yes the rules are descriptive of how native speakers speak. But as a learner you have to learn them as if they are prescriptive.

Comment: @StefanieGauss You misunderstand what ‘rules’ means here. It’s not like laws that someone more or less arbitrarily made up and now everyone has to learn them and abide by them. Language is a system with rules that govern how that system is used; we all unconsciously abide by them every time we speak, but unlike laws, we don’t necessarily _know_ them consciously – we have to extrapolate them from how we speak, through analysis. Just like the laws of physics: we didn’t write or invent them, we just describe how we observe them to work. So yes, native speakers _do_ follow all those rules, just →

Comment: → like the world and universe around us follow the rules of physics.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet just like in Cantonese, you'd not say "thank you" if somebody gives you a glass of water, it is more like the "custom" or common habit. So from these habits, the "rules" *can be* written in a textbook to teach foreigners how to speak to sound native. However, it is not like people in Hong Kong "follow the rules". It is more like it is how they commonly say things

Comment: I want to distinguish between grammar and "polite custom".  In English, when someone sneezes you say "Bless you", not "Get better soon", or "Please don't sneeze".  Those phrases are correct grammar, but not "polite custom".  On the other hand, "I'll consider to go fishing" is incorrect grammar.  Just like "You blesses"  is incorrect grammar. Do you see the difference between "grammar" and "custom"?

Comment: @StefanieGauss As James says, there’s a difference between socially expected phrases and customs, and the grammar that determines whether or not a sentence is well-formed. Even so, you can analyse and describe the logic that governs both, and in both cases it’s based on the fact that native speakers do follow that logic. The fact that “that’s how people say it” is precisely what _makes it a rule_. If people didn’t say it like that, it wouldn’t be a rule. If native speakers said, “I will consider go fishing”, then that would be the rule; but they don’t, ever, so it’s not.

Comment: it may not be "polite custom" but just "custom" or "habit". You are viewing "thank you" as polite custom but tell you what, in Cantonese, people say both "I will consider swimming later" or "I will consider to train myself in martial arts", so they are both grammatical. You are saying, no, in English, the second form is not grammatical. Well, why? Ultimately, it is just people don't say it this way